# How is spark HiveContext/SQLContext retrieving schema/data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can't seem to find much documentation on it but when I pull data from Hive in Spark SQL how is it retrieving the schema, is it automatically looking in the Hive Metastore? Also is it Hive telling spark to look at the file location to pull the data into a DataFrame? And how does it handle a view or can it not handle a view yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it looks up hive metastore.
2. Spark delegates hive queries to hive. It captures output and turn it to a dataframe of rows. 
   From docs:

> When working with Hive one must construct a HiveContext, which
>   inherits from SQLContext, and adds support for finding tables in the
>   MetaStore and writing queries using HiveQL

Comment: if i want to run the sparl sql code which connecting hive meta store using eclipse standalone mode, where should i place the hive-site.xml file? is there any other way to configure hivecontext properly?

Comment: Are you sure about point 2? In hivecontext, Spark reads meta data from hive metastore and supports hiveQL but don't think delegates queries to hive, do you have any links to support point 2?